# How to setup a pypiserver with docker with custom a authentication?

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I have a [pypiserver](https://hub.docker.com/r/pypiserver/pypiserver) docker installed.

The problem is that I cannot upload my Python package (Getting 403 Forbidden)

I'm trying to figure out:

1. Does it have a default username/password I'm not aware of?
2. I know I can add the arguments "-P -a" to disable authentication but how can I do that with docker? What should I write in:

   my-pypiserver:
   image: pypiserver/pypiserver:latest
   command: <?>

**edit:**
When adding `-P . -a .` I'm getting the following error:

> Error: while trying to list root(/home/pypiserver/packages): [Errno 2]
> No such file or directory: '/home/pypiserver/packages'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the following error because the `Dockerfile` sets `/data` as `workdir`. Since your're manipulating the `entrypoint` it looks like pypi-server has lost that and use the default (/home/pypiserver/packages).

> Error: while trying to list root(/home/pypiserver/packages): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pypiserver/packages'

Can you try the following?

`docker run pypiserver/pypiserver:latest  -P . -a . /data/packages`